# Passing custom vertex structure to GLSL shaders

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to pass a structure to a simple GLSL vetrex shader.
Here's how the structure look like on the C++ side:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float position[3];
    char boneIndex[4];
    float weights[4];
    float normals[3];
    float textureCords[2];
};
```

Is it possible to pass array of this vertex to the vertex shader without creating a separate array for each component?

Can I do something like this:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 MVP;

layout(location = 0) in struct Vertex
{
    vec3 position;
    uint boneIndex;
    vec4 weights;
    vec3 normals;
    vec2 textureCords;
} vertex;

out vec2 UV;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertex.position, 1.0f);
    UV = vertex.textureCords;
}
```

(Dont mind that not all of the components are in use, it's just for the example.)

And if I can, how can I pass the data to it from the C++ side using the glVertexAttribPointer() function? (According to my understanding you can pass only 1,2,3,4 to the **size** parameter).

Is it the even the right way to do things?
I'm a beginner in OpenGL programming so if you have an answer please don't hesitate to include obvious details.

### Edit:

I ended up doing something like this:

```
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);  //float position[3]
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 12, (void*)0);    //char boneIndex[4]
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 16, (void*)0); //float weights[4]
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, (void*)0); //float normals[3]
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 44, (void*)0); //float textureCords[2]


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indiceBuffer);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
```

On the C++ size, and on the GLSL vertex shader:

```
    #version 330 core

uniform mat4 MVP;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in int boneIndex;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 weight;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 UVCords;

out vec2 UV;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    UV = UVCords;
}
```

But it still won't work, the model wont render correctly

Comment: Each of the fields of your structure when using an interface block is assigned a sequential location. Anything `vec4` or smaller uses a single attribute location, things like `mat4` use 4 locations (it might help to think of them as an array of 4 `vec4`s). So assigning with `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: So actually I can use the same C++ code used to pass the data to this shader?
layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in uint boneIndex;

C++ OpenGL:
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...

Will it work the same?

Comment: I have not seen the actual C++ code you use for this, but it should work. I would also point out that the bone index should be passed with `glVertexAttribIPointer (...)` because it is an integer field whereas all of your other vertex data are floating-point.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman Please see the updated question, can you see something wrong in that code?

Comment: You have to add subsequent offsets to the attributes and correct stride information. When using two attributes of size `n`, first will have offset `0` and stride `2n`, and the second offset `n` and *the very same stride*. Once you get that it'll be easy to do it for more than 2 attributes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you've used to transfer the interleaved data is correct (that is, using `glVertexAttribPointer`, however, your last two parameters are incorrect).

The penultimate is the `stride` (which is the same for every item in the struct, and should be the size of the struct), and the last is the `offset`, which should be different for each element (as they are at different offsets in the struct itself).

Also it is best not to use constants here, but instead, use the `sizeof()` operator, to make your code as platform independent as possible.

Here's what it should look like:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), nullptr
); //float position[3]

glVertexAttribIPointer(
    1, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
    std::reinterpret_cast<void *>(offsetof(Vertex, boneIndex))
); //char boneIndex[4]

glVertexAttribPointer(
    2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
    std::reinterpret_cast<void *>(offsetof(Vertex, weights))
); //float weights[4]

glVertexAttribPointer(
    3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
    std::reinterpret_cast<void *>(offsetof(Vertex, normals))
); //float normals[3]

glVertexAttribPointer(
    4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
    std::reinterpret_cast<void *>(offsetof(Vertex, textureCoords))
); //float textureCoords[2]
```

Also, you should probably ensure that your `Vertex` struct is not packed to fit into a nice word boundary. This is done by using `#pragma pack(0)`, if your compiler supports it. (Remember to reset this after after your struct, because otherwise the compiler will use this directive throughout the rest of the compilation process, and all your aggregate data structures will be structured in a way that doesn't yield to the best possible fit with regards to world alignment.), here's what that looks like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 0)

struct Vertex {
    float position[3];
    char  boneIndex[4];
    float weights[4],
          normals[4],
          textureCoords[2];
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It solved my problem! I read the documentation for this functions on: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml And it got me a bit confused about those lase two paramteres. About the pack directive, it is not needed because the struct is organized in a way the does not require padding.

Comment: Glad to hear it, I've just changed it to use the `offsetof(...)` function, seeing as it makes a bit more sense than hardcoding the `sizeof()` values. Read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/)

Comment: You can't be sure about how a system will pack your structs, so it's always safer to specify the directive and have nothing go wrong, than not and get odd errors when you try and port to some obscure system with 3 word boundaries.

Comment: Why would any compiler insert padding in this struct? Where will he put them? And for what reason?

Comment: Well put it this way, you stand to lose nothing by adding `#pragma pack(...)` directives, and what's more it is made clear to those reading your code that this data is not intended to be padded, whereas if you *don't* add them, it is possible that later on down the line, you'll get an obscure bug, either because you added an extra element to your struct, or because your compiler padded it and you weren't expecting it. I'm not telling you that the compiler *will* pad your struct, just warning you to be prepared if it does. In the end it is your call, my recommendation, however, stands :P

Comment: @amnn Is it even efficient? I have heard that packing structures has bad effects like reducing performance and hardware exceptions. Even There's no standard and compiler independent way to do it. The only thing is alignas in C++ that has a completely different idea. personally I can't use this way to avoid packing in members of the struct that are struct.

Comment: Yes, CPU reads from packed structs can be slower because their fields can be mis-aligned, which is why you shouldn't pack structs by default (it leaves the compiler less flexibility to optimise), but this is only relevant if packing changed the layout, in which case it's also important for the correctness of uploading vertex attributes to the GPU.

Comment: Because the answer uses `offsetof`, padding between fields in a struct should be taken care of.  The only remaining risk is if `sizeof(T)` does not account for the padding necessary to maintain the alignment of `T`, but I don't think that's the case -- so I may have been overzealous requiring both packing and using `offsetof` and `sizeof` -- it's one or the other (pack and use constant offsets, or don't and use `offsetof`/`sizeof`).